# Build auto suggestions using external file

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, autosuggest

I am trying to build auto suggestions using external file using FileDictionaryFactory. However, it is always expecting file from zookeeper config.

How can i give external location instead of uploading to zookeeper?

I am using following configuration in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/suggestdocid" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">80</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggestdocid</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggestdocid</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>

<searchComponent name="suggestdocid" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
 <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">suggestdocid</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="storeDir">suggester_analyzing_dir_docid_dict</str>
      <str name="highlight">false</str>

    <str name="dictionaryImpl">FileDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="sourceLocation">/var/lib/solr/doclist.txt</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">doc_token</str>
      <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
      <str name="nonFuzzyPrefix">3</str>
      <str name="preserveSep">false</str>
      <str name="maxEdits">0</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Following is the configuration used for doc_token in schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="doc_token" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"
                splitOnNumerics="1"
                stemEnglishPossessive="0"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When i tried to build suggestions, i am getting following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Error opening /configs/my-collection//var/lib/solr/doclist.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the single core version (i.e. not the Zookeeper version) allows placing the file outside of the core directory either.. The file is loaded using the active [resource loader for the core: `core.getResourceLoader().openResource(sourceLocation)`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/spelling/suggest/FileDictionaryFactory.java). This also matches [Resource and plugin loading](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/resource-and-plugin-loading.html#resources-and-plugins-on-the-filesystem).

Comment: You could inherit the FileDictionaryFactory and implement your own resource loading, but that would require you to put the .jar file in zookeeper and load it from there .. in that case, you could probably upload the doclist instead (depending on size) and get automagic replication.